# Libreoffice dysfonctional mail merge

Tags: libreoffice, mail

Ubuntu 19.10/LibreOffice 6.3.5.2

Mail merge (by email) does not work. I checked:

- the db calc document contains a column with valid emails
- the SMTP connection from libreoffice was tested
- In the mailing assistant, I can browse the documents with the data from the base
- In the email assistant, the TO list is set with the email field from the calc document

Then next when asking to send the documents, the dialog is locked to "0 document(s) on 3 sent." for ever and nothing is sent of course.

[image]

Any ideas or work around?

If there are known working alternatives to Libreoffice mail merge, I am interested to read about.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I installed latest OpenOffice 4 and mail merge by email works out of the box.